# Perfect numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

Define a Perfect (capital-P) number as a natural number that is equal to the sum of its Divisors **excluding 1 and the number itself**. (So the Divisors of 28 are 2, 4, 7, 14, summing to 27.)
Is there any such Perfect number?
If yes, give an example.
If no, prove it.

Comment: So you would have to start among the numbers usually defined as "abundant"...

Comment: That's not a question: it's a command! Have you tried to find an example?

Comment: So you want $\sigma_1(n)=2n+1$, where $\sigma_1(n)$ is the sum of all divisors of $n$. A useful property is that, if $m$ and $n$ are coprime, we have $\sigma_1(mn)=\sigma_1(m)\sigma_1(n)$.

Comment: Also, $\sigma_1(n)$ is odd iff $n$ is of the form $2^rk^2$.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a start. If there are no squared factors of the number $N=\prod p_i$, where prime factors are $p_i$ then the sum of the factors is $$\prod(p_i+1)-1-N=N$$ so that $\prod (1+p_i)$ is odd and $p_i$ is even. Clearly this is impossible for a solution.

Looking more closely we see that we get a product of terms of the form $$\prod \frac {p_i^{n_i+1}-1}{p_i-1}=2N+1$$where $N=\prod p_i^{n_i}$. Each term in the product has to be odd, and this means that $p_i=2$ or $n_i$ is even. And you need $2N+1$ to be suitably composite.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for a ["Quasiperfect number"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiperfect_number). It's open whether such things exist (but if they do, they must be odd squares larger than $10^{35}$ and have at least seven prime factors).

Comment: ... well I guess this means I can kill my search now. I was at $10^9$ only.

Comment: @LJL Well, I guess you can start with $10^{35} + 1$ now.